# Matplotlib how to dotplot variable number of points over time?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to build an audiofingerprint algorithm like Shazam.

I have a variable length array of frequency point data like so:

```
[[69, 90, 172],
 [6, 18, 24],
 [6, 18],
 [6, 18, 24, 42],
 []
...
```

I would like to dotplot it like a spectrogram sort of like this. My data doesn't explicitly have a time series axes but each row is a 0.1s slice of time. I am aware of plt.specgram.

[image: dotplot]

Comment: Use a [`scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) plot. Beyond that, it's a bit difficult to know what your actual question is.

Comment: @tom10 I'm trying that now but get `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence` because there are a variable number of points per time slice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.repeat` can create an accompanying array of x's.  It needs an array of sizes to be calculated from the input values.

Here is an example supposing the x's are .1 apart (like in the post's description, but unlike the example image).

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# ys = [[69, 90, 172], [6, 18, 24], [6, 18], [6, 18, 24, 42]]
ys = [np.random.randint(50, 3500, np.random.randint(2, 6)) for _ in range(30)]
sizes = [len(y) for y in ys]
xs = [np.repeat(np.arange(.1, (len(ys) + .99) / 10, .1), sizes)]
plt.scatter(xs, np.concatenate(ys), marker='x', color='blueviolet')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]